# Generating all 4 digit unique code in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of alphabets + numbers like `[0,1,2,..,8,9,a,b,c,...x,y,z]`. I want to generate all 4 digits alphanumeric unique codes which will start with `0000` and the last code will be `zzzz`. 
The series will look like `0000, 0001, 0002, ...., 000z, 0010, 0011, ...001z,....zzzz`.

I am struggling to write this code. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.product` like so:

```
from itertools import product

# your list needs be all-characters
lst = ['0','1','2','3', ... 'a', 'b', ... 'z'] 
print(["".join(item) for item in product(lst, repeat=4)])
```

Which will produce:

```
0000
0001
...
zzzz
```